# How to prevent PHP game from re-instantiating from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My game keeps re-instantiating from the AJAX call so turn 1 is repeated over and over again.

I tried making an if statement to check whether the array of objects is empty or not but it requires $game inside the if statement to check that and it gives an error because $game is not declared until the next line.

```
<button type="button" onclick="slap()">Slap</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function slap() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"playgame.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "POST", //request type
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The playgame.php file

```
<?php
    include 'game.php';

    $game = new Environment();
    $game->InitialiseGame();
    $game->DisplayStatus();

    if($game->arrayOfBees[0]->typeOfBee == "Queen") {
        $game->slap();
        $game->RemoveDeadBees();
        $game->DisplayStatus();
    } else {
        echo "The Queen died, game over!!";
    }
```

I want the $game to be only instantiated and initialised once, and then on the second AJAX call, only the if-else statement is executed. At the moment the whole playgame.php file is called every-time the button is pressed, and I cannot see a way round this?

Comment: keep a `ready` variable. on the first success, set ready to true so you don't have to do more ajax requests.

Comment: I am confused as to how this would work? From what the other guys said, it sounds like this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is pretty much irrelevant here. You'd get the same problem no matter how the HTTP request was made.

HTTP is stateless. Each request reruns your program anew.

You need to explicitly store the state yourself. A common approach for this is a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) (if you want to store the data on a per-user basis) or [database](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (if you want to store it as data that multiple people can share).

Comment: Uhm, the explanation of the storage engine for a session is only internally relevant, but session data itself is always related to the [software that provides the session identifier, commonly called] "browser".
Where or how the session data is persistet on the server(s) is irrelevant either.
Relevant is the [technique to retain a persistence level over an stateless connection, commonly called a] "session".

Comment: So you guys are both saying that a session is what is needed here?